# Use of backpropagation for weight updates in a combination of 2 neural networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

Every neural network updates its weights through back-propagation. 
Suppose a neural network model is stacked over another neural network model, how is backpropagation used for weights updation in such architecture. What difference in updation of weights is seen wrt single neural network model?

Comment: There are many hidden layers in NNs; what is "the hidden layer" to which you refer?

Comment: Your stacking isn't clear: "each neural network is stacked over one another."  I'm not familiar with such a topology.  For instance, a CNN-LSTM model is a CNN model stacked on top of an LSTM model, but the LSTM is *not* also stacked over the CNN.  Can you explain?

Comment: Each neural network has its own hidden layer. When CNN model is stacked on top of an LSTM model, do we consider hidden layer of both model or hidden layer of outer model(LSTM)?Yes, you are correct about CNN model stacked over LSTM model

Comment: Each model has multiple hidden layers.  All of them get updated during back-propagation.

Answer (score 1):

A CNN, GAN, or any other neural network topology is still composed of basic units, the layers of the network.  "CNN" refers to one broad class of topologies; "GNN" is another broad class.

Back propagation works the same way as usual: each layer's weight changes are propagated to the previous layer, divided by the gradient for that weight.  This is an operation between layers that are adjacent (directly connected) in the topology.  Whether both layers are within a sub-graph we've clustered as a "CNN", or they're adjacent layers in two different sub-graphs, does not matter -- it's a straightforward layer-to-layer update.